# NetTopologySuite distance between polygon and point in meters

Tags: postgis, .net, nettopologysuite

I want to get distance between polygon and point in meters. When I'm using Distance() method I get it in cartesian units. How can I get in meters? I tried looking for solution but I can get only how to transform two points to do that. I don't know how to do this with polygon. Maybe there is a way to get closest point from polygon to second point?

The main idea of that app is to check is my vehicle is in area (polygon) and if not, check how far it is.

Comment: Do you mean that you have data for example in EPSG:4326, and you get distances in degrees, but you would like to get meters instead? That is not supported by NTS "An excerpt from JTS website explains the capabilities of NTS too: "The JTS Topology Suite is an API for modelling and manipulating 2-dimensional linear geometry. " You can re-project your data into some suitable projected coordinate system and get distances then. Or let PostGIS do the job with geography data type.

Comment: So you mean to execute internal postGIS command and avoid using netTopologySuite method in this case?

Comment: That would be a clean solution and PostGIS knows how to do the job https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html "For geography types defaults to return the minimum geodesic distance between two geographies in meters, compute on the spheroid determined by the SRID. If use_spheroid is false, a faster spherical calculation is used." But javascript alternatives do exist, search "Haversine distance".

Comment: I found other solution. I used class DistanceOP to calculate the closest point in polygon to my point. Then, when i have 2 points, it is easy to calculate real distance in meters, for example using Spherical Law of Cosinus.